# Hardy-Littlewood circle method applied to the binary problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am having trouble understanding the application to this problem:
[image: binary]
I think this means the number of combinations of two numbers from the sets $A_1$ and $A_2$?
Now [Alessandro Zaccagnini](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250371477_Introduction_to_the_circle_method_of_Hardy_Ramanujan_and_Littlewood) goes on to show the solution (below) and I do not understand why $A$ x $A$ in $(a_1,a_2)\,\epsilon\, A$ x $A$? Why would the sets be multiplied?

[image]

Comment: We are looking for pairs of nonnegative integers which sum to $n$. A pair of nonnegative integers is an element of $\mathbb{N}^2 = \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$. Here we are looking for those pairs that have the additional property that the first belongs to $A_1$ and the second to $A_2$, that is, for elements of the subset $A_1 \times A_2 \subset \mathbb{N}^2$ summing to $n$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I cannot understand why its N multiplied by N and not N + N surely its out of 2 N numbers?

Comment: It's the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets (which may be the same set).